# Twitter (Tweepy): What counts as a search API call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to find out the maximum number of API calls I can make in each 15 minute interval using Twitter's API. However, I still don't understand what exactly counts as an API call and how the limits work.

First, what counts as a 15 minute interval? Does this mean that I have a set number of calls determined by the hour, so every day I can make 450 requests between say 9:30 and 9:45, or is it determined by the time I make my first API call, so I can make 450 requests after the first one is made?

Second, using the search API, I can see that I can make [450 requests for each 15-minute interval](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets). What counts as a request? In Tweepy, I can call

```
    searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=topic, tweet_mode='extended').items(1000)]
```

to get 1000 tweets about topic, where topic is a String. How many API calls would this be? Since it seems that the limit of the query size count is 100 per call, is Tweepy making 10 calls? Or, since the default is 15, is Tweepy making 100/15 calls? Is there anything that I'm not doing to maximize efficiency?

Basically, I am trying to get as much data per Twitter API possible. I still don't fully understand what counts as a time window, and how Twitter determines Search API calls. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,  1 API call == 1 HTTP request (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).
With twitter they measure this in 15 minute increments. In 15 minutes, you can do X number of Y request type and endpoint.
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting

Twitter also provides you with headers on the response that help you to prevent hitting the rate limit:

```
x-rate-limit-limit: the rate limit ceiling for that given endpoint
x-rate-limit-remaining: the number of requests left for the 15 minute window
x-rate-limit-reset: the remaining window before the rate limit resets, in UTC epoch seconds
```

So in pseudo-code you can  `if request.response.headers['x-rate-limit-remaining'] <= 2:` and halt or do something else until the reset time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if I understand correctly, if I start at 9:29, I couldn't max out my requests, wait for 9:30, and max out my requests again. Also, if I make one HTTP GET request of a query, where I specify the count in the GET request to 100 (Twitter's max), that would only count as one request. Therefore, could I theoretically get 4500 Tweets per 15 minutes by running 450 GET requests of size 100?

Comment: The doc doesn't seem to specify a timestamp. Some systems use rolling windows (requests in the last 15 minutes from now) or static windows 0-15, 15-30, 30-45, 45-60. In either case, they give you the exact time that it resets in the response headers.

Comment: Great, I'll look into this. Thanks for being helpful, I really appreciate it! Have a great day!